# Sending Email error using c# and hosted in goddady plesk host

Tags: c#

I have tried almost all the c# code to send email but always I face the same error. I hosted my site to Plesk host of goddady. 
I tried this code as well,
https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-email-using-systemnetmail-19291
and much more code that the other said its working for them but I don't know why it is not working to me. but in local host it work.
I face only to this error:
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.28.108:587

Here is c# code:

```
    protected void sendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       bool connection = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
       if (connection == true)
       {

           string to = "*****@gmail.com"; //To address    
           string from = "*****@gmail.com"; //From address    
           MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

           string mailbody = "In this article you will learn how to send a email using Asp.Net & C#";
           message.Subject = "Sending Email Using Asp.Net & C#";
           message.Body = mailbody;
           message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
           message.IsBodyHtml = true;
           SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); 
           try
           {
               client.Send(message);
           }

           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               throw ex;
           }  

       }
       else
       {
           Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Please check your Internet connection.');</script>");

       }



    }
```

Here is Web.config code:

```
 <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="*****@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="*****@gmail.com" password="*****" enableSsl="true" port="587" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: looks like godaddy might be blocking it, is there options to open up the firewall?

Comment: I have tried other port as well but i face the same error.... any way thanks